# Ошибка review of the query string passed to accepts any user input в обобщённом классе

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, строки, рефлексия

Создаю дженерик класс доступа к данным с простыми CRAD операциями. Использую рефлексию, через неё заполняю Parameters для SqlCommand.

Но CommandText необходимо задавать напрямую. Иначе коданалайзер ругается:

```
review of the query string passed to accepts any user input
```

Так как класс обобщённый я не могу жёстко задать количество параметров в строке (например, в методе create)- так как предпологается, что он будет работать с разными таблицами.

```
command.CommandText = "insert into tableName (@p1, @p2 ..) values(@p1_value, @p2_value ..);";
```

Что нужно провернуть, чтоб не нарушить безопасность, но и успокоить анализатор?

Comment: Отчего бы не использовать какую-нибудь ORM?  EF или Dapper?

Comment: @tym32167 задание запрещает пользоваться orm

Comment: _он будет работать с разными таблицами_ - не делайте так. Для каждой таблицы создайте свой набор запросов.

Comment: Использовать параметр для задания имени таблицы _невозможно_.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov на счёт параметра имени таблицы - спасибо, проверил- правда нельзя.
на счёт отдельного репозитория для каждой таблицы- изначально идея была в том, чтоб уменьшить количество кода за счёт одного класса. (допустим если у нас 20 таблиц в бд)

Comment: По сути, выход только один: создавать строку запроса динамически. С помощью обычных строковых операций (конатенация/интерполяция/форматирование) подставляем имя таблицы, имена колонок, имена параметров.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, да, вы правы. Хоть как раз на динамическое создание строки анализатор и ругался. Не нашёл другого выхода как подавить это предупреждение.

Comment: О каком анализаторе речь?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, microsoft.netcore.analysis ошибка CA2100
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2100?view=vs-2019

Comment: Ну тут либо подавить предупреждения анализатора, либо вместо обобщённого метода `Insert<T>(T entity)` сделать набор конкретных методов: `Insert(User user)`, `Insert(Product product)` и т. д. Это гарантирует не только безопасность от sql-инъекций, но и безопасность типов. Я практически уверен, что вы используете `AddWithValue`. Уже много раз приводил ссылку: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Из-за возможного неправильного приведения типов можно получить плохую производительность.